# TypeError: Bad Operand Type for abs(): 'ReferenceFrame' but I have no abs() function

Tags: python, curl, vector, typeerror, sympy

I'm trying calculate the curl of a vector with its del operator, and so I'm using the curl from sympy and just having the vector cross with the reference frame, but I get this error: what exactly am I doing wrong?

```
import sympy 
import numpy as np
import math 
from sympy import Symbol, diff, Array, sin, cos, curl
from sympy import init_printing
from sympy.physics.vector import curl, ReferenceFrame
init_printing()

# Variables being used - B0 is the initial mag field, alpha is a  constant. x/y/z are for the direction
alpha = Symbol('\u03B1')
B0 = Symbol('B0') 
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
print ('Symbols: ', alpha, B0, x, y, z)

# This has the reference frame and the vector
R = ReferenceFrame('R')
V = B0*sin(alpha*x)*R.y + B0*cos(alpha*x)*R.z
print(V)

C = curl(V,R)
print(C)
```

I'm expecting a /nabla operator cross the vector.

Comment: Show the full traceback (as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: What are B0, alpha, R?  SYmbols?  Show how you initial them.  Give us some that works with copy-n-paste.

Comment: I edited my question with the constant and what they're used for

Comment: According to the docs and code, `curl` expands the calculation, with `dot` and so on.  It runs for me and prints `0`.

Comment: I'm literally supposed to get alpha* the vector back as the curl. But I don't understand how I'm getting the error that I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `R[0]` instead of `x`.  I deduced this from the `curl` examples (and trying to replicate some Wiki examples)

Running in `isympy`

(Can't import `curl` from `sympy`)

```
In [2]: from sympy.physics.vector import curl, ReferenceFrame  
   ...: alpha = Symbol('\u03B1')  
   ...: B0 = Symbol('B0')    
   ...: R = ReferenceFrame('R')  
   ...: V = B0*sin(alpha*R[0])*R.y + B0*cos(alpha*R[0])*R.z  
   ...: print(V)  
   ...: C = curl(V,R)  
   ...: print(C)  
   ...:  
   ...:                                                                              
B0*sin(R_x*α)*R.y + B0*cos(R_x*α)*R.z
B0*α*sin(R_x*α)*R.y + B0*α*cos(R_x*α)*R.z
```

There may be a way of factoring out the `alpha`, or otherwise show that `C` is `alpha*V`.  I'm just working through the `sympy` tutorials.

```
In [4]: expand(C-alpha*V)                                                            
Out[4]: 0

In [8]: V                                                                            
Out[8]: B₀⋅sin(Rₓ⋅α) r_y + B₀⋅cos(Rₓ⋅α) r_z

In [9]: C                                                                            
Out[9]: B₀⋅α⋅sin(Rₓ⋅α) r_y + B₀⋅α⋅cos(Rₓ⋅α) r_z
```