# Vector equation in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to set up a vector relation and be able to solve for a certain variable.

```
from sympy.physics.vector import *
from sympy import * 

t,l = symbols("t l")
R = ReferenceFrame('R')
eq1 = Eq(5*R.x + t*R.y, l*R.x + 4*R.y
solve(eq1,t)
```

Why do I get this error? Not implemented? How can I accomplish the same thing?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    Eq(5*R.x + t*R.y, l*R.x + 4*R.y)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 474, in __new__
    lhs = _sympify(lhs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 418, in _sympify
    return sympify(a, strict=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 340, in sympify
    raise SympifyError(a)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: SympifyError: 5*R.x + t*R.y
```

Comment: It looks like `Eq` is not able to deal with the `ReferenceFrame`. Do you have other examples making use of this combination?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean. Do you know an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786392/typeerror-bad-operand-type-for-abs-referenceframe-but-i-have-no-abs-func) is relevant?

Comment: I would consider this to be a bug in SymPy. I would suggest opening an issue for it in the issue tracker https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues